# $P(x)$ is a polynomial of least degree and $f(x)$ is a differentiable function for all $x\in R.$Find the degree of the polynomial $P(x).$

Tags: calculus

Let $$f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             0  & x\leq0 \\
             \\ P(x) &0<x<1 \\
             \\ 1 &x\geq1
             \end{array}
   \right.$$

where $P(x)$ is a polynomial of least degree and $f(x)$ is a differentiable function for all $x\in R.$

Find the degree of the polynomial $P(x).$

---

As $f(x)$ is a differentiable function, it has to be a continuous function.
So $P(0)=0,P(1)=1,P'(0)=0,P'(1)=0$
Here I am stuck; how can I find the least degree of $P(x)?$

Comment: Linear obviously won't work. Nor will quadratic because you need zero derivative at $x=0$ and $x=1$. So you expect the answer to be 3. Can you find a cubic $P(x)$ with $P(0)=0,P(1)=1,P'(0)=P'(1)=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four conditions are good to find the four coefficients of a cubic polynomial. Just verify that the unique cubic polynomial doesn't "accidentally" have lower degree (you can in fact see that beforehand as in *almagest*'s comment).